# Python Challenge Lvl 3 Explaination (warning spoilers!)

Tags: python, regex

I am doing the Python challenge and while I figured out the answer to a puzzle, I did it in a hacky, not-very-good way. Upon advancing I was able to see the solution which is:

```
string1 = open('text.txt').read()
print ''.join(re.findall('[^A-Z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}[^A-Z]', string1))
```

I messed with this for a while, removing a caret here and seeing what happens, changing a braced group there. However, I just cant wrap my head around why this works. Could anyone explain it in a easy to understand way?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide more context.  Python Challenge level 3 is not accessible unless you have completed levels 1 and 2.  What is the challenge?  What data is given?  Also, be more specific about what you don't understand about the regular expression -- perhaps explain what you do understand.

Comment: your explanation below was perfect. Thank you! It's just frustrating that I cant seem to get that from the python regex documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled the pattern as verbose to include inline comments:

```
pat = re.compile('''
    [^A-Z]    # any character except a capital letter
    [A-Z]{3}  # three capital letters
    (         # the beginning of a capturing group
    [a-z]     # one lowercase letter 
    )         # the end of the group
    [A-Z]{3}  # three capital letters
    [^A-Z]    # any character except a capital letter
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Demo:

```
>>> re.findall(pat, 'AAAAaBBBbBBBBzzZZZxXXXyYYYYwWWWvABCn')
['x', 'v']
```

Comment: This is from the Python re docs: " "^" (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline. " Why am I failing to understand that language to read "the caret acts to indicate we are searching for NOT this?

Comment: also, how does it relate to the "$" which "Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string" ?

Comment: The `^` (caret) has a different meaning inside of `[]` (square brackets).  The square brackets indicate a character set.  From the docs: "If the first character of the set is '`^`', all the characters that are not in the set will be matched."

Comment: Ah yes! I see now within the docs, under [], it explains how the caret behaves within square brackets. Thank you so much for your wonderful explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`([a-z])` captures a single small letter.

`[A-Z]{3}` matches 3 uppercase letters (on both sides).

`[^A-Z]` ensures that there isn't a 4th uppercase letter (*"EXACTLY three"*).

Comment: `[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}` doesn't this mean exactly a small letter on the the middle with 3 big letters on the sides?

im confused as to why `[^A-Z]` this needs to be in there

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez because the small letter should be surrounded by *exactly* 3 capital letters. Removing `[^A-Z]` would allow *more* than 3 capital letters.

Comment: oh ok now I knda get it.
so if that's the case then can the solution be `[a-z][A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3} [a-z]` as well?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez `[a-z]` is not equivalent to `[^A-Z]` (hint: digits)

Comment: ok I get it now. I didn't think there were digits in that puzzle anyway thank yo u very much  @Stefan

Answer (score 2):

[^A-Z] a char that is not a capital letter

[A-Z]{3} three capital letters

([a-z]) lowercase letter that you match

repeat the first two.

Comment: This is from the Python re docs: " "^" (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline. " Why am I failing to understand that language to read "the caret acts to indicate we are searching for NOT this?